# How can use {{ block ... }} for a phtml file

Tags: blocks, phtml

I want to use `{{block type="blog/blog" name="blog" alias="list_blog" template="aw_blog/bloghome.phtml"}}` in `phtml` file, but I don't know how, because this code useable for `cms` page but I need output of this line in a `phtml` file.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this?

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('blog/blog')->setTemplate('aw_blog/bloghome.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: I test it in local and every thing is ok but when I use it in file that is uploaded on server my home page messed up. How can I fix it?